# iPhone app crash when post images in progress and interrupt by phone call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

In my application, when I add image in the image view and start posting images on the server in a synchronous way, at that time if I receive any call then my application is crash with following Logs :

```
2012-12-14 11:13:19 +0000 Test_Phone_Call URL : https://app.factorlab.com/mvc/media
2012-12-14 11:13:19 +0000 Test_Phone_Call Response Message : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2012-12-14 11:13:24 +0000 Test_Phone_Call URL : https://app.factorlab.com/mvc/media
2012-12-14 11:13:24 +0000 Test_Phone_Call Response Message : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2012-12-14 11:13:28 +0000 Test_Phone_Call URL : https://app.factorlab.com/mvc/media
2012-12-14 11:13:28 +0000 Test_Phone_Call Response Message : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2012-12-14 11:13:32 +0000 Test_Phone_Call URL : https://app.factorlab.com/mvc/media
2012-12-14 11:13:38 +0000 backboardd Forcing crash report of Test_Phone_Call[4610]...
2012-12-14 11:13:38 +0000 backboardd com.factorlab.grow.stage failed to resume in time
2012-12-14 11:13:39 +0000 backboardd Application'UIKitApplication:com.factorlab.grow.stage[0xe310]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
2012-12-14 11:13:39 +0000 backboardd Finished crash reporting.
```

Can we fix this crash or there is no way to fix it. I am testing on iPhone 4 with iOS 6.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make network requests on the main thread you are guaranteed to run into these kinds of problems. You should move your network requests to a background thread or else do them asynchronously.